# Bootstrap dropdown menu cutoff on mobile

Tags: css, mobile, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, z-index

My dropdown menu works fine normally - https://i.stack.imgur.com/B11yE.jpg
But is covered by widgets on mobile - https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3olJ.jpg
And is even covered by the chart on mobile - https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gs5lW.jpg

Shouldn't they render the same?? AND what could be the source of the problem? and how can I fix this issue?

### Details

Some styling details:

```
.dropdown-menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  display: none;
  float: left;
  min-width: 160px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  margin: 2px 0 0;
  list-style: none;
}
```

### NOTES

1. There is no z-index on the overlapping elements.
2. The entire content of the page has a `snap-content` class which sets the `z-index: 2;`. This is to let me use the snap.js plugin.

Comment: Have you tried putting the z-index of the dropdown menu to say 10 or 20???

Comment: Just tried it - no luck

Comment: did you try it with important at the end of it like this: `z-index: 20 !important;`

Comment: yes - exactly - I'm checking it in chrome on my desktop before loading it in my iPad simulator

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they *should*, but it's not uncommon that they *don't*.  This is why cross-platform HTML, JS and CSS is such a PITA, and why, if you're good at it you print money.

Comment: Any thoughts on what the problem could be?

Comment: Ah, but that's not what you asked.  Would you like to update your question?